# TkInter ListBox and use of .format

Tags: python, string, tkinter, string.format

I am using this command:

```
self.licenseBox.insert(END, "{:30}{:90}{:20}{:5}".format(item[0],
                                                    item[1], item[2], item[3]))
```

But .format will add the item then the column width. For example `if item[0] = "foo"`, the first column is 33 wide and means the following parameters are off by three.

Any work around ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But .format will add the item then the column width.

format() does no such thing:

```
print "1234567890" * 2
print "{:4}{:4}{:4}{:4}".format('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd')

--output:--
12345678901234567890
aaaabbbbccccdddd
```

The total width of the output is 16 = 4 x 4.

You should explicitly specify the alignment:

```
lb.insert(tk.END, "{:<5}-{:<2}".format(123, 9))
```

The docs say:

```
'<'   Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space 
      (this is the default for most objects).
```

That 'most objects' language is what I think you may be running afoul of. Strings, numbers, etc. have a `__format__()` method that is called when they are asked to display themselves when you call the format() method on them.  Check this out:

```
print "{:4}".format("a")
print "{:4}".format(9)

--output:--
a   
   9
```

Strings and numbers have different defaults for their justification.  So I would not rely on the defaults--be explicit instead, and then you will know how the output will be justified.

Having said that, I have to use 17 for the min field width to actually get 10:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x200")

lb = tk.Listbox(root, width=150)
lb.insert("1", "{:4}{:4}".format("a", "b") )
lb.insert(tk.END, "1234567890" * 4)
lb.insert(tk.END, "{:<17}{:<10}".format(100, 200) )
lb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

With that code, I see 200 starting in column 11. Okay, that alignment problem has to do with tkinter using a default font that is not fixed width, i.e. all characters do not occupy the same amount of space.  If you are trying to align columns, you need to use a fixed width font.  Try something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

root = tk.Tk()

my_font = tkFont.Font(family="Monaco", size=12)  #Must come after the previous line.

root.geometry("1000x200")

lb = tk.Listbox(root, width=150, font=my_font)
lb.insert("1", "{:4}{:4}".format("a", "b") )
lb.insert(tk.END, "1234567890" * 4)
lb.insert(tk.END, "{:>10}{:>10}".format(100, 200) )
lb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Apologies for leaving out that when I print it the alignment is fine. When added to the ListBox it appears as I mentioned earlier... Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying it out with a Listbox.  I remember this problem from long ago.

Comment: @user2522202, When I explicitly specify the alignment, it works--example in post.

Comment: Awesome that worked, it was something I would have never thought of. You're a legend !

Comment: @user2522202,  Which problem were you wrestling with?  The default alignment problem or the font problem?

Answer (score 1):

Windows

```
listbox = Listbox(master, width=60, font='consolas')
```

I am on linux, where `font='mono'` works.